# R parse date with strptime

Tags: r, strptime

I am trying to parse the following date:

```
> strptime("2013-09-04T15:00:11.454+03:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d%t%H%M%%S%z")
[1] NA
```

without success.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: formatting dates is made much easier with lubridate: 
x =("2013-09-04T15:00:11.454+03:00"); library(lubridate); ymd_hms(x)

Comment: This is as close as I can get with `strptime()`: `strptime("2013-09-04T15:00:11.454", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` Note that you had `%t` for a literal `T`, you were missing literal `:`, you had a literal `%` bc you included `%%`, and I had to remove the time offset as `%z` is documented to take a modifier of form `-0800` (or `+0800`) and your modifier has a `:` in it.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Hm does not seem so:  `ymd_hms("2013-09-04T15:00:11.454+03:00")` yields `"2013-09-04 12:00:11 UTC"`, `ymd_hms("2013-09-04T15:00:11.454")`  yields `"2013-09-04 15:00:11 UTC"`.

Comment: you can get it with `strptime` by subbing out the colon in `+03:00`. seems like the `%z` format only accepts the form `[+-]dddd`, ie, with no hour/second separators `tt <- gsub('(?<=\\+\\d{2}):', '', tt, perl = TRUE); strptime(tt, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z", tz = 'EST')`